# Spring autowiring scanning only test files

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, junit

During unit tests with JUnit, Spring autowiring is only working for files in:

```
src/test/org/baudo
```

But not files in:

```
src/main/org/baudo
```

So when I test my DAO that autowires a sessionFactory object, the result is my session factory is null. Then I get the following stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.baudo.dao.MyDAO.addPerson(MyDao.java:46)
at org.baudo.dao.MyDaoTest.testAddPerson(MyDaoTest.java:53)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

This is my configuration for scanning components:

```
 <context:component-scan base-package="org.baudo" />
```

The fact is that I have two packages with the same name (one for testing and one under main).

What can I do in order to scan all the files for autowiring (and not only under test dir)?

Further information:

I'm using Spring MVC and Hibernate with Maven

This is my test DAO:

```
@RunWith( SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class )
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"/spring-servlet.xml"})
public class MyDaoTest {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory; // This contains a value

    // Other stuff here
}
```

This is my DAO:

```
public class MyDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory; // This is null

    // Other stuff here
}
```

My Dao is under:

```
 MyProject\src\main\java\org\baudo\dao
```

My test is under:

```
 MyProject\src\test\java\org\baudo\dao
```

My spring-servlet.xml also contains

```
<context:annotation-config />

<tx:annotation-driven />
```

This is the way I defined my bean:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="configLocation">
        <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
    </property>
    <property name="configurationClass">
        <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Should I add something else to make it working?

Comment: How is the session factory bean defined? If you didn't define any, how could Spring autowire one into your DAOs?

Comment: Added bean definition in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely reason is that you are creating the MyDao object directly and not via Spring `BeanFactory`. You have to either autowire the DAO you want to test into your test class:

```
// Here live the annotations ... 
public class MyDaoTest {
    @Autowired
    private MyDao myDao;

    @Test
    public void testSomething() {
        // Do what you need with myDao
    }
}
```

or use AspectJ compiler/weaver and ask spring to "advise" the `new` operation

```
<context:spring-configured />
```

Comment: This is working, for some reason only the test namespace is scanned, so I have to create all the dao as a bean into the test class.